# Tensorflow API For testing the data

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have a dataset with 5 columns, I am feeding in first 3 columns as my Inputs and the other 2 columns as my outputs.

I have successfully executed the program but i am not sure how to test the model by giving my own values as input and getting a predicted output from the model.

Can anyone please help me, How can I actually test the model with my own value after training is done ?

I am using Tensorflow in Python. I am able to display accuracy of testing,but How do I actually predict with value if I pass some random input (here,I need to pass 3 input values to get 2 output values)

Here is my code:

```
# Implementation of a simple MLP network with one hidden layer. Tested on the iris data set.
# Requires: numpy, sklearn>=0.18.1, tensorflow>=1.0

# NOTE: In order to make the code simple, we rewrite x * W_1 + b_1 = x' * W_1'
# where x' = [x | 1] and W_1' is the matrix W_1 appended with a new row with elements b_1's.
# Similarly, for h * W_2 + b_2
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

RANDOM_SEED = 1000
tf.set_random_seed(RANDOM_SEED)


def init_weights(shape):
    """ Weight initialization """
    weights = tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(weights)

def forwardprop(X, w_1, w_2):
    """
    Forward-propagation.
    IMPORTANT: yhat is not softmax since TensorFlow's softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits() does that internally.
    """
    h    = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w_1))  # The \sigma function
    yhat = tf.matmul(h, w_2)  # The \varphi function
    return yhat

def get_iris_data():
    """ Read the iris data set and split them into training and test sets """
    df = pd.read_csv("H:\MiniThessis\Sample.csv")
    train_X = np.array(df[df.columns[0:3]])
    train_Y = np.array(df[df.columns[3:]])
    print(train_X)

    # Convert into one-hot vectors
    #num_labels = len(np.unique(train_Y))
    #all_Y = np.eye(num_labels)[train_Y]  # One liner trick!
    #print()
    return train_test_split(train_X, train_Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)

def main():
    train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = get_iris_data()

    # Layer's sizes
    x_size = train_X.shape[1]   # Number of input nodes: 4 features and 1 bias
    h_size = 256                # Number of hidden nodes
    y_size = train_y.shape[1]   # Number of outcomes (3 iris flowers)

    # Symbols
    X = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, x_size])
    y = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, y_size])

    # Weight initializations
    w_1 = init_weights((x_size, h_size))
    w_2 = init_weights((h_size, y_size))

    # Forward propagation
    yhat    = forwardprop(X, w_1, w_2)
    predict = tf.argmax(yhat, axis=1)

    # Backward propagation
    cost    = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=yhat))
    updates = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

    # Run SGD
    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(3):
        # Train with each example
        for i in range(len(train_X)):
            sess.run(updates, feed_dict={X: train_X[i: i + 1], y: train_y[i: i + 1]})

        train_accuracy = np.mean(np.argmax(train_y, axis=1) == sess.run(predict, feed_dict={X: train_X, y: train_y}))
        test_accuracy  = np.mean(np.argmax(test_y, axis=1) ==sess.run(predict, feed_dict={X: test_X, y: test_y}))

        print("Epoch = %d, train accuracy = %.2f%%, test accuracy = %.2f%%"
              % (epoch + 1, 100. * train_accuracy, 100. * test_accuracy))


    correct_Prediction = tf.equal((tf.arg_max(predict,1)),(tf.arg_max(y,1)))
    best = sess.run([predict], feed_dict={X: np.array([[20.14, 46.93, 1014.66]])})
    #print(correct_Prediction)
    print(best)


    sess.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, this answer takes some assumptions on the input, which you did not provide in your original question.

At this point I think your homework will require some more work to be finished. The 4th and 5th column are probably the petal width (a real value) and the Iris type (encoded as a category). This means that as a result you will probably need a real valued output (petal width) and a categorical prediction. This means that your softmax_cross_entry_with_logits will probably not play nicely with the petal width. Also you are applying an argmax as part of the prediction and this willl return the index with the highest value (in this case the petal width or the catergorically encoded value) which also does not make sense. So as a debugging aid why not start with:

```
print(sess.run([yhat], feed_dict={X: np.array([[20.14, 46.93, 1014.66]])})
```

This will print out yhat, (based upon the inputs `[20.14, 46.93, 1014.66]` (that's a massive flower, completely unlike anything inside the dataset) and will contain 2 outputs.

Comment: Basically,my data is as follows:    14.96, 220, 300 ,400, 500...........All the inputs(i,e,. values in first 3 columns are numbers) as well as all the outputs(i,e, values in next 2 columns  are also numbers). So,Basically,I need to print two output numbers for given 3 input numbers

Comment: And is your data in the last two columns continuous or discrete ? Is there any relation between the two ?

Comment: the data in the last 2 columns is completely discete: My data is as follows:  A,V,AP columns are inputs,                                                                                                   AT          V           AP         RH            PE
14.96 41.76 1024.07 73.17 463.26
25.18 62.96 1020.04 59.08 444.37
5.11 39.4 1012.16 92.14 488.56
20.86 57.32 1010.24 76.64 446.48
10.82 37.5 1009.23 96.62 473.9
26.27 59.44 1012.23 58.77 443.67
15.89 43.96 1014.02 75.24 467.35
9.48 44.71 1019.12 66.43 478.42
14.64 45 1021.78 41.25 475.98
11.74 43.56 1015.14 70.72 477.5

Comment: To be discrete, they look extremely continuous ... which is going extremely off topic of your initial question, this smells like a regression problem rather than a classification problem.

Comment: Yes,this is a regression problem ,not classification..Sorry,for that..Was not able to exactly frame my question! Would be glad,if you can help me!